# EditText Bug on AndroidStudio 2.2.3, SDK 25

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

Is there a problem with EditText? I updated my Android Studio to 2.2.3 then suddenly all my EditText don't show the Soft Keyboard. I tried every possible means that I know, to force it to show but none worked.

I was thinking that it has to do something with the setShowSoftInputOnFocus() method that is only available from SDK 21 up. Unfortunately I'm working on STBs running on SDK 17 and 19.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pass set the value of `setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false)` then it will always hide the keyboard for EditText even it is having focus.

If you want to show keyboard on EditText focus set its value true instead of false

You can find it's details from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShowSoftInputOnFocus(boolean)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  I think that is self explanatory. My problem here is that setShowSoftInputOnFocus is only included in SDK 21 my apps run on 17 and 19 because that is the SDK supported by my STBs.  Before updating to Android 2.2.3 all my EditText were fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Someone messed up with the settings of my test device.

Thank you